# How to get output from http request in aws lambda

Tags: node.js, http

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {

// TODO implement

const https = require('https');
https.get('https://reqres.in/api/users',
res => {
    //console.log(res.statusCode);
    //console.log(res.headers);

    let body = '';

    res.on('data',data =>{
        body += data;
    })

    res.on('end',()=>console.log(body));

})

const response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify(https.get),
};
return response;
};
```

I got an error, it seems that I cannot get the output from the todo function, so I tried the response function and it still generates an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use callback function:

```
exports.handler = (event, callback) => {

  const https = require('https');
  https.get('https://reqres.in/api/users',
    res => {
      let body = '';
      res.on('data', data => {
        body += data;
      });

      res.on('end', function() {
        const response = {
          statusCode: 200,
          body: JSON.stringify(body),
        };
        callback(response)
      });
    });
};

this.handler(null, (res) => console.log(res));
```

the callback will be called when `end` is fired.

Answer (score 0):

I like the promise way, resolve the `promise` `on end` event, reject the promise `on error` event.

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {

  const https = require('https');

  try {
    const responseBody = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      https.get('https://reqres.in/api/users',
      res => {
        //console.log(res.statusCode);
        //console.log(res.headers);

        let body = '';

        res.on('data', data => {
          body += data;
        })

        res.on('error', (err) => reject(err));

        res.on('end', () => resolve(body));

      })
    });

    const response = {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify(responseBody),
    };
    return response;
  } catch(err) {
    const errorResponse = {
      statusCode: 400,
      body: JSON.stringify({ message: err.message }),
    };

    return errorResponse;
  }
}
```